# PySpark apply same StringIndexer on multiple columns

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have the following Dataframe

```
+--------------+---------------+   
|       SrcAddr|        DstAddr|   
+--------------+---------------+  
| 192.168.100.5| 192.168.220.16|  
| 192.168.100.5| 192.168.220.15|  
|192.168.220.15|  192.168.100.5|  
|192.168.220.16|  192.168.100.5|  
| 192.168.100.5| 192.168.220.15|  
|192.168.220.16|  192.168.100.5|  
| 192.168.220.9|  192.168.100.5|  
| 192.168.100.5|  192.168.220.9|  
| 192.168.220.9|  192.168.100.5|  
+--------------+---------------+
```

containing source and destination address IPs.
I want to transform them in numerical index by means of StringIndexer, but I want to learn a common mapping between the columns.

Unfortunately StringIndexer does not provide such a rich interface in PySpark. Thus I found a workaround, but I wanted to know if there is a better way to do it.

What I have done is the following:
First, I compute the union between the two columns

```
src_addr_df = df.select(["SrcAddr"]).withColumnRenamed("SrcAddr", "Addr")  
dst_addr_df = df.select(["DstAddr"]).withColumnRenamed("DstAddr", "Addr")  
all_addr_df = src_addr_df.union(dst_addr_df)
```

Then, I learned a common StringIndexer over the newly created DataFrame:

```
addrIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="Addr", outputCol="AddrIdx")  
addrModel = addrIndexer.fit(all_addr_df)
```

Finally, I used the learned model to transform the original dataframe. This, is the tricky part because I need to rename the columns quite often to obtain the desired results:

```
df = addrModel.transform(df.withColumnRenamed("SrcAddr", "Addr")).withColumnRenamed("Addr", "SrcAddr").withColumnRenamed("AddrIdx", "SrcAddrIdx")

df = addrModel.transform(df.withColumnRenamed("DstAddr", "Addr")).withColumnRenamed("Addr", "DstAddr").withColumnRenamed("AddrIdx", "DstAddrIdx")
```

Thus, I'm wandering if there is the possibility to rather change the InputCol value of the StringIndexer, which would create a much readable code

Best regards,
Sandro